# SAS Enterprise Guide - importing date data that contains gibberish as well

Tags: date, datetime, sas, etl

Regarding SAS Enterprise Guide and importing data. I have a column of data, some of which is in a date format and some of which is gibberish.  Is there a way to force convert the column to date format (MMDDYY10.) and convert all the gibberish (non date format) information to blanks?

Comment: By gibberish do you mean letters, special characters, or only numbers? You can check if the field is a date, if it is, ok, if it's not, you can redirect it to other variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks some information, but I assume that you are using `proc import` to read the file. That procedure doesn't provide any control over how to read each column, as it internally determines the type and structure of the data. In your case, if the file you are importing is a text file such as CSV and the internal scan cannot read the column as numeric then it reads it as character to preserve the information which is the right thing to do. The main purpose of `proc import` is to create a SAS data set from an external file format. You can post-process the data after the initial import.

Another option for you is to use the Import Wizard which steps you through a series of dialogues to gather information about the file you are importing. One of the steps allows to specify the type and format of the data in each column. For the date column in question, you can specify the appropriate date informat and get the desired result in your output data set. Additionally, a final step in the wizard gives you an option to save the import code to a file so that you can use it in the future to import more data from a similarly structure file. The code is a data step with the appropriate `infile`, `informat`, `format` and `input` statements from the information gathered from you in the wizard.

Of course, the ultimate in control is to write the data step yourself. I prefer to do this even with simple, well-structured files, because I can precisely control the type and length of variables and have the full power of the data step at my disposal. Once I develop a working version of the code, I find that's easier to modify if the future to adapt to changes in the input file.

Hopefully, this gives you options to solve your date problem.